# Inheriting a method from a class interface by subtyping argument: is it possible?

Tags: c#, .net

Let's say I inherit from IMyManager a SetModel. If I implement it I would normally write:

```
using lib.model;

namespace MyComponents
{
    public class MyManager:IMyManager
    {

        public void SetModel(ILibModel model)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

That's fine for compiler.

Now let's say that instead of ILibModel  I pass a concrete class MyModel which implement ILibModel.

Why compiler doesn't accept this whereas MyModel is of type ILibModel :

```
namespace MyComponents
{
    public class MyManager:IMyManager
    {

        public void SetModel(MyModel model) {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `MyModel` implements `ILibModel` the reason this does not work is because while all `MyModel` types are `ILibModel` types, the inverse does not hold true.  That's to say not all `ILibModel` types are `MyModel` types.

The interface explicitly states that it MUST take `ILibModel` types.  So an implementation that takes just `MyModel` does not meet your interface contract, because of the fact that a type, say `MyOtherModel` that also implements `ILibModel` is a valid type to be passed in based on your interface's contract.

The only way around this would be to potentially use generics on the interface.  An example being:

```
public interface IMyManager<TModel>
    where T : ILibModel
{
    void SetModel(TModel model);
}

public class MyManager : IMyManager<MyModel>
{
    void SetModel(MyModel model)
    {

    }
}
```

However, you may run into issues with co-variance and contra-variance with such a system.

Comment: the inverse does not hold true but I'm not in the inverse case. The problem is rather than this stupid interface just doesn't automatically do casting whereas It should.

Comment: Thanks for generics will see if it can fit.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are supplying an overload for the SetModel function. As far as the compiler is concerned, perhaps you want to allow the programmer to do something more specific with the concrete type, while doing something else with the interface version.

Answer (score 1):

because someone could later write:

```
((IMyManager)myManager).SetModel(new OtherClassThatImplementsILibModel());
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the `IMyManager` defines `SetModel` that way.